# CSS Menu Maker Drop Down Menu CSS not loading until page refresh

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I just implemented a CSS Dropdown Menu from [CSS Menu Maker](http://cssmenumaker.com/) and it seems to be working great but only after you refresh the page. If you go to [Euro Dressage Center](http://www.eurodressagecenter.com) you will see my navigation menu at the top appears without the CSS applied. When you then refresh the page it shows as it should. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works for me on the first load

Comment: um well that makes me feel better it may just have been something on my end. Can a few more people try it please and reply so I am sure it was just me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just visited your site and it seems to be working fine on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer 9. It seems to only be an issue on your end

Answer (score 0):

I'd put this as comment, but still don't have enough points. Maybe your problem is that your browser is caching the old styles. Open it in a different window preferably in "Privacy mode" or erase your history and caches; that might solve the problem.

Hope it helps.